# how to prevend loading div for 2nd time after .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using this ajax script for uploading files. All the files are outputted in the div `.myFiles`
When uploading a new file, i use `$(".myFiles").load(" .myFiles");` in the success to see the result immediately that a new file is added. But when i look into the dom, this is what is created:

```
<div class="myFiles">
    <div class="myFiles">
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i prevent that the `.myFiles`  div is created in the already existing `.myFiles`?

This is my ajax:

```
function ajax_file_upload(file_obj) {
        if(file_obj != undefined) {
            var form_data = new FormData();                  
            form_data.append('file', file_obj);
            $.ajax({

                type: 'POST',
                url: '',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,

                beforeSend: function () {
                    $(".uploadspinner").show();
                },

                success:function(response) {
                  //$(".echo").html(response);
                  $('#selectfile').val('');
                  $(".myFiles").load(" .myFiles");
                  $(".uploadspinner").hide();
                  $(".uploadarea").hide();

                }




            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused. You're making an Ajax call to a blank URL, and not even doing anything with the `response` in the `success` callback. I'm really not sure what you're trying to do here, but whatever it is it doesn't appear to require Ajax.

Comment: Well, the php code to handle the upload is on the same page as the js, so thats why the url is empty

Comment: But, that just doesn't make sense. It means you're making an Ajax call to the same endpoint that produces the page the user is on, so the response will just be another copy of that HTML document. More to the point, though, in this code it doesn't make the slightest bit of difference what URL you are pointing at, because you do nothing that depends on the response.

Comment: ok. Can you show me the correct way to use the ajax script for this?

Comment: @RobinZigmond there is nothing special wrong. a `GET` and `POST` can return different content.

Comment: @JackMaessen would you consider simply reload the page after upload?

Comment: @apple appple :yes simply page reloading is enough, at least: reload the `<div class="myFiles">` so that the added file after upload is immediately visible in the div

Answer (score 2):

you can use .append() function instead of load.

instead of $(".myFiles").load(" .myFiles")
use $(".myFiles").append("");

Answer (score 2):

Its not a big issue but if you want not the same div appears twice, then i would say make this your html:

```
<div class="myFiles">
   <div class="outputFiles">

   stuff goes here

   </div>
</div>
```

And use this in your `success`:

```
success:function(response) {
              //$(".echo").html(response);
              $('#selectfile').val('');
              $(".myFiles").load(" .outputFiles");
              ***

            }
```

Result: you have only 1 `.myFiles` div and 1 `.outputFiles` div

Comment: Awesome! Works great